# jOrgChart Configuration options (where do I put these to make them work?)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a tree organization chart and I started using a plug-in called jOrgChart. On the website it says it has 3 configuration options and one of them is dragAndDrop. I dont know where to actually put this in my code to make it work, by default it says it is set to false. And please don't say just set it to true.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#org').jOrgChart();
});
```

here's a picture of the area of the website
[image]
 Any ideas?

Here's the link: [jOrgChart](http://th3silverlining.com/2011/12/01/jquery-org-chart-a-plugin-for-visualising-data-in-a-tree-like-structure/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the documentation for it on GitHub: https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart#readme

It says that in order to use the drag and drop functionality you must also include jQuery UI on your page.  So you would need to include that script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And in their [example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html) I viewed the source code to find out how to set the dragAndDrop option:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#org").jOrgChart({
    dragAndDrop  : true
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I was doing this: $('#org').jOrgChart(dragAndDrop(true))